# Spark Streaming Dynamic allocation leading to increase in processing time

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I was running an spark streaming application with one minute of batch duration and the spark.dynamic.idlexecutorTimeout was also same (60s), with this configuration my average processing time was ~3 seconds. When I reduced the timeout to 30 seconds my avgerage processing time is 25sec and for some period it rose to 4 minutes, due to which my total delay increased to 15 minutes.

Is the sudden spike the result of starvation of executors? If yes then how to check it? What is the reason for increased processing time and can we resolve that?

[image]

Comment: I saw your other question about allocation and now this one. I'm not sure your original processing times allow for dynamic allocation. Yes, you will have some resource underutilization with fixed resource assignment, but it does guarantee a stable system.  The cost of dynamic allocating/deallocating resources is too high for a streaming system. (it was also the case for the predecessor of dynamic allocation, called "fine-grained scheduling" on Mesos). IMO, dynamic allocation is meant for interactive workloads, like notebooks, that might be idle for relatively long periods of time.

Comment: But if I won't go for dynamic allocation then I will be wasting a lot of resources.Also my ultimate goal is to compare Spark Streaming and Samza    in terms of resources so I can leverage dynamic allocation for optimizing the resource usage by my app.

Comment: Maybe reduce the resource fixed allocation instead of going for dynamic allocation?

Comment: Can you also tell me the reason for this increased processing time. What I think is that it is due to the reallocation of containers at the start of next batch , am I right?